# Informatica cloud parameter file

Tags: cloud, informatica

I am generating text files through Informatica cloud data synchronization task.
i have to dynamically zip those text files with timestamp through a batch script called from post processing command from the DSS task. But zip files name will be changed on the basis of country code.

suppose, i have to extract account text files for 2 countries, germany and sweden.
 source connection is: salesforce
 target connection is: flat file
i have passed the country codes in the parameter files.
i.e, $$country_code=SE
     $$country_code=DE

Now when the outbound text files will be generated, it will be generated like,
 for Germany, Account_DE_YYYYMMDDHHMISS.txt
 for Sweden,  Account_SE_YYYYMMDDHHMISS.txt

Please help how to dynamically change this file name with the batch script called from post processing command through parameterization in informatica cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Below link helps in understanding the post processing command to archeive files

https://network.informatica.com/docs/DOC-15089

Instead of timestamp, pass country name as parameter.